# AspectJ as android library module dependency

Tags: java, android, gradle, aop, aspectj

I wanna use AspectJ in my library module dependency, I followed this tutorial: http://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/

But I can't make it work, the problem is my code just won't execute:

build.gradle:

```
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
import org.aspectj.bridge.IMessage
import org.aspectj.bridge.MessageHandler
import org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.1'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 4
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.9'
  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
  provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
  provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
  LibraryPlugin plugin = project.plugins.getPlugin(LibraryPlugin)
  JavaCompile javaCompile = variant.javaCompile
  javaCompile.doLast {
    String[] args = ["-showWeaveInfo",
                     "-1.5",
                     "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                     "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                     "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                     "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                     "-bootclasspath", plugin.project.android.bootClasspath.join(
        File.pathSeparator)]

    MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
    new Main().run(args, handler)

    def log = project.logger
    for (IMessage message : handler.getMessages(null, true)) {
      switch (message.getKind()) {
        case IMessage.ABORT:
        case IMessage.ERROR:
        case IMessage.FAIL:
          log.error message.message, message.thrown
          break;
        case IMessage.WARNING:
        case IMessage.INFO:
          log.info message.message, message.thrown
          break;
        case IMessage.DEBUG:
          log.debug message.message, message.thrown
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

def isReleaseBuild() {
    return version.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}

allprojects {
    version = VERSION_NAME
    group = GROUP

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And my Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class HandlerAspect {
  private static final String POINTCUT_METHOD =
      "execution(@com.henorek.discharge.annotations.HandleException * *(..))";

  private static final String POINTCUT_CONSTRUCTOR =
      "execution(@com.henorek.discharge.annotations.HandleException *.new(..))";

  @Pointcut(POINTCUT_METHOD)
  public void methodAnnotatedWithHandleException() {}

  @Pointcut(POINTCUT_CONSTRUCTOR)
  public void constructorAnnotatedHandleException() {}

  @Around("methodAnnotatedWithHandleException() || constructorAnnotatedHandleException()")
  public Object weaveJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    String className = methodSignature.getDeclaringType().getSimpleName();
    String methodName = methodSignature.getName();

    Log.d("DUPA", "DUPA");
    Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
    Log.d("DUPA", "DUPA");
    return result;
  }

  @AfterThrowing(value = "methodAnnotatedWithHandleException() || constructorAnnotatedHandleException()", throwing = "exception")
  public Object testJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable exception) throws Throwable {
    Log.d("DUPA", "DUPA");
    Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
    Log.d("DUPA", "DUPA");
    System.out.println("dupa");
    return result;
  }
}
```

My annotation is simple class + constructor annotation. I'm executing code in another module in this project called sample, as the name says its just activity where I created method

```
@MyAnnotation
void test() {
}
```

I call this method on button click but it didn't log anything, did I miss something? My code looks exactly the same as example above.

Of course I added my :library module to :sample module dependencies.

Comment: have you edited your settings.gradle? Also if you look in the current sources for this blog there is a change of how bootloader is added (may be not related)    
`"-bootclasspath", project.android.bootClasspath.join(File.pathSeparator)]`

Comment: Please, try [my gradle plugin](https://github.com/Archinamon/GradleAspectJ-Android), it consistently supports application and library modules as well. Will be appreciate for any feedback :)